# Creating a database with ASP.NET Core RC 2 and Entity Framework core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is a very broad and general question. Please advise.

I have tried starting an ASP.NET core project but have failed when it came to generating the database.

I could not get anything to work. I have lost my code while reinstalling studio.

Would some one be so kind to instruct and provide a working example of the context and startup classes(and etc)?

I would greatly appreciate if you would also provide an example of installing and working with the `dotnet` commands.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create the database using Entity Framework code first, just like previous versions of ASP.NET. It's a little different though, as you don't use Visual Studio, but rather you open up cmd.exe.  Navigate to the project's src folder, then enter the following commands:

dotnet ef migrations add firstMig -c *DbContextName*

This will create a folder named migrations inside the project, along with an initial migration file and a 'firstMig' file (which is the name of the migration we are creating.  These migrations will be used to update the database with the following command:

dotnet ef database update -c *DbContextName*

I have recently released a blog post, which is a tutorial that goes over step by step how to setup [ASP.NET RC2 with Entity Framework code first on a PostgreSQL database](http://totaltechware.blogspot.com/2016/05/aspnet-core-rc2-web-app-with-postgresql.html).  Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Hello Mr.Hardy.

I have not found your previously but I appreciate the input.
Thank you!

Sadly I was in a rush, so I just moved the project to version 4.5.2 for show resons.

Thank you once more

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **EF core 1.0 RC2**, you can scaffolding your existing database in looking at following steps :

1. **Install Entity Framework from Package Manager console**

   - Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Pre
   - Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Pre
     *(this can take a while to complete)*
   - Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design -Pre
2. **Open project.json** and locate the tools section, if the following code is'nt present, add it

   "tools": {
   "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools":{
   "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
   "imports": {
   "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
   "portable-net45+win8"
   }
   },
3. **Reverse your model in Models directory**

   - goto your project directory : cd\src\myproject (*one level* before Models dir)
   - run :
     Scaffold-DbContext "'Server=servername;Database=databasename;Trusted Connection=True'" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver -OutputDir Models

**N.B.** = I'm using MS SQl Server. If you experiment problem update to the latest PowerShell tool from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

#### For the database

I'm not sure if database migrations are fully supported yet. For now, I'm setting things up manually, which isn't bad or cumbersome at all. What this means is I create a blank database, then run a set of scripts against it to create and populate tables. I then write the context and model classes by hand.

Here is a sample project I've put together: https://github.com/mw007/adventure-works. It's very simple and doesn't do much, but is meant to showcase everything working.

It's an ASP.NET Core RC2 application, with EntityFrameworkCore and PostgreSQL support via [NpgSQL](http://www.npgsql.org/). The context and model classes are in the `Models` directory.

Feel free to comment back with any specific questions about the context or model. The database scripts I referenced earlier are in the `dockerfiles/adventureworks` directory.

#### For the dotnet commands

Generally, there are two things you'll want to remember: `dotnet restore` and `dotnet run`.

`dotnet restore` pulls down all dependencies defined in your `project.json` file.

`dotnet run` runs your app (or anything specific defined in your `project.json`).

Comment: Hello Dave.

Thank you for replying.
I have considered doing all the things manually.

but I have used ASp.net core rc 1 before with migrations.
Can I use the previous versions somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can still target RC1 in your project.json, but my experience has been that RC2 is much more stable to work with. Further, in reading the [EntityFrameworkCore RC2 announcement blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-rc2/), it appears migrations **are** supported. I'll do some more digging and get you info on how to make it work.

Comment: Ifyou succed - I will be greatful for the information.
Sadly I've spen most of the day working on this problem with no succes.

Comment: Here are [the docs](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/dotnet.html#dotnet-ef-database-update) detailing how to use them. There is also this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5509) filed about it. The added thing here is that if you're using Visual Studio, there is a checkbox in the Publish wizard as explained by Rowan Miller (an ASP.NET team member).

Comment: I will work on an example/tutorial, and hopefully have it to you tomorrow.